# How do I remove the no results message when the box field is clear

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search, filter

I am currently using the following code to create a filter list. Once a user tries to search for something and the no result message appears, which works correctly for me. If the user deletes the letters from the search box and the box is empty how do you hide the no results message. Do I need to add some extra code to the Java Script or can this done in the CSS code area?

```js
function myFunction_search() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var found = false;

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (filter !== "" && a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

      li[i].style.display = "block";
      found = true;
    } else {

      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("no_result_msg").setAttribute("style", "display:" + (found ? 'none' : 'block'))
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('images/search-icon.png');
  background-position: 4px 4px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
    
#no_result_msg {
  display: none;
    
    }       

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
    
#myUL li {
  display: none;
    }

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction_search()" placeholder="Search for product names or product codes.." title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="no_result_msg" id="no_result_msg"><i><u>No Results found</u></i></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a div having the message, then show or hide it based upon the search result found or not.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var found = false;

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (filter !== "" && a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

      li[i].style.display = "block";
      found = true;
    } else {

      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("no_result_msg").setAttribute("style", "display:" + (found ? 'none' : 'block'))
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li {
  display: none;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>My Phonebook</h2>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
  <ul id="myUL">
    <div id='no_result_msg'>No Results found</div>
    <li><a href="www.google.com">Adele</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>

  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ah thanks for your help that has worked for me, just added some extra css code to hide it when the users enters this page for the first time: "#no_result_msg {display: none;}" Again thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Glad , it helped you.

Comment: once you get the no result message appear, and the user clears the box so its blank how do you hide the "no result message" when the box field is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, i, c, a = false;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        no_result = document.getElementById("no_result_found")
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            c = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (c.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1) {
                a = true;
            }
            if (filter !== "" && a) {
                no_result.setAttribute("style", "display: none")
                li[i].style.display = "block";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        if (!a) {
            no_result.setAttribute("style", "display: block")
        }
    }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
    
#myUL li {
  display: none;
    }

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL">
<div id='no_result_found' style="display: none;">No result found</div>
  <li><a href="www.google.com">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
  
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```